# Make formbox with responsive inputs+labels

Tags: html, css

I need to make a formbox-popup that will have a not-fixed width (based on the width of another element which is in turn based on the width of the page).

The popup should show 1/2/3/n columns, depending by the width of the popup itself.

This is an example of the code I have currently:
http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/eItyu

```
.box {
  width: 500px;
  outline: 1px solid purple;
  .row {
    display: inline-block;
    label {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 50px;
    }
    input {
      width: 120px;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that I need a way to make the inputs+labels large enough to fill the entire width of the box.

So my example should looks like this:
http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/cIDFs

The only solution I can find is to use media-queries, but it doesn't look a very clean solution.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using CSS tables:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/6w2RJ/1/)**

### Markup

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="row">
        <label>label</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
     <div class="row">
        <label>label</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.box {
  width: 500px;
  outline: 1px solid purple;
  display:table;
}
  .row {    
    width: 50%;
    display: table;
    float:left;    
}
label {

    width: 50px;
    display: table-cell; 
}
input {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by javascript or jquery,here is a example if you want to show one column

```
$('input').each(function(index,input){
  var _this = $(input);

  //box width
  var w1 = _this.parent().width();
  //label width
  var w2 = _this.prev().width();

  _this.css('width',w1 - w2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use an **adaptable object**, as you mentioned that the quantity of columns may vary, my proposal is a **responsive design**, so you addapt the quantity of columns on the width of the popup, so the media queries, as you mentioned, is the best suitable solution (in my opinion):

## the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JP2x6/)**

## html:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="row">
         <label for="input">Label:</label>
        <input type="text" id="input"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <label for="input">Label:</label>
        <input type="text" id="input"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <label for="input">Label:</label>
        <input type="text" id="input"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <label for="input">Label:</label>
        <input type="text" id="input"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <label for="input">Label:</label>
        <input type="text" id="input"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <label for="input">Label:</label>
        <input type="text" id="input"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

## css:

```
.box{
    width:100%;
}
.row {
    float:left;
}
.row label{
    display:inline-block;
    width:25%;
}
.row input{
    width: 68%;
}

@media screen and (min-width:250px){
    .row{width:100%;}
}
@media screen and (min-width:500px){
    .row{width:50%;}
}
@media screen and (min-width:750px){
    .row{width:33%;}
}
@media screen and (min-width:1000px){
    .row{width:25%;}
}
@media screen and (min-width:1250px){
    .row{width:20%;}
}
```